# can sftp remove trailing space before file transfer form file with huge size?

Tags: sftp

I've a remote file with huge size. The reason is that is generated with a lot of trailing spaces. Is it possibile to remove them before the transfer?

Comment: What "sftp"? Are you asking about the protocol in general or about specific SFTP client (like OpenSSH command-line `sftp`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to remote system with `ssh`:

```
ssh user@server "sed 's/ \+$//' /path/to/remote/file" > /path/to/local/file
```